# How to remove an element if the first substring is duplicated in a list of strings?

Tags: c#, linq

I got a case where I want to remove the element from the list, if the "968934" part is identical before the comma is duplicated in another element.

If the substring part is duplicated, I want to only keep the "655" element in the list. If it is not duplated, I want to keep the element regardless.

How can I do this?

> 968934,655,814
>
> 968934,123,814

Answer (score 4):

Supposing that you get your inputs from a file, you could simply create a dictionary where the Key is the first substring, and while reading the file you add the substring to the dictionary if not present. At the end the values will contains the full line that starts with that key but only one time

```
Dictionary<string, string> keys = new Dictionary<string,string>();
foreach(string line in File.ReadLines("yourInputFile.csv"))
{
    if(!keys.ContainsKey(line.Split(',')[0]))
        keys.Add(line.Split(',')[0], line);
        // or, if you want only the second element
        //keys.Add(line.Split(',')[0], line.Split(',')[1]);
}
```

Now your unique lines are easily retrieved with a simple

```
string[] values = keys.Values.ToArray();
```

Of course, all those splits can be executed just one time adding an intermediate array variable and then work with that

```
Dictionary<string, string> keys = new Dictionary<string,string>();
foreach(string line in File.ReadLines("yourInputFile.csv"))
{
    var splittedLine = line.Split(',');
    if(!keys.ContainsKey(splittedLine[0])
        keys.Add(splittedLine[0], line);
        // or, if you want only the second element
        //keys.Add(splittedLine[0], splittedLine[1]);
}
```

Comment: But would this approach take account to if the substring part 2 is of "655" value?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. You have asked to have a single line where many lines have the same first substring equal. And the line choosen should be the first encountered while reading the file or your in memory array. This solution consider only the first substring to be the key. If you have two strings where the first and second part are equal but the third is different then only one string will be returned

Answer (score 0):

have you considered using a group by and a split

```
IEnumerable<string> ids = new List<string> {
    "968934,655,814",
    "968934,123,814"
};
ids = from i in ids
      group i by i.Split(',')[0] into g
      select g.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

With LINQ and GroupBy where you group by the first segment of the string and remove it if there are multiple items with same fist segment.

```
var items = list
    .Select(s => new 
    { 
        FirstPart = s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf(',')), 
        String = s
    })
    .GroupBy(s => s.FirstPart)
    .SelectMany(g => g.Count() == 1 
        ? new[] { g.First().String } 
        : g.Select(x => x.String.Substring(x.FirstPart.Length + 1)))
    .ToList();
```